# Importing email addresses into Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to import a CSV file that will update users in our AD environment with their proper email addresses.

The first few lines of the CSV look like this:

```
Email,Name
adam.lambert@domain.com,Adam Lambert
aaron.smith@domain.com,Aaron Smith
arthur.aardvark@domain.com,Arthur Aardvark
```

The PowerShell script I've written looks like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$data = Import-CSV -Path "C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\importtest.csv"
Foreach ($user in $data){
Get-ADUser -Filter “Name -eq ‘$($user.Name)'” | Set-ADUser -Replace @{mail = “$($user.Email)”}
}
```

However, much to my dismay, it doesn't work. To clarify, I am trying to match the ADSI value of "name" (not the SamAccountName) with the list in Excel, which I know for a fact are exact matches.

Any thoughts? Error is below:

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'Name -eq ‘Adam Lambert'' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '10'.
At line:4 char:11
+ Get-ADUser <<<<  -Filter “Name -eq ‘$($user.Name)'” | Set-ADUser -Replace @{mail = “$($user.Email)”}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error parsing query: 'Name -eq ‘Adam Lambert'' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '10'. 
   ,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: Your code here has "smart quotes" all over it. Is this because you copy/pasted it from Word or something, or does your real code have them? Make sure your code uses standard double quotes `"` and single quotes `'`.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a back tick in that string:

shouldn't it be:

```
"Name -eq '$($user.Name)'"
```

Comment: A "smart quote" actually (see above comment). But that definitely solved the issue. Thanks guys!